# How to disable "Map only" view mode?

Tags: qgis, qgis-3

In the view menu, there's an option called "Toggle Map Only." I selected that option to see what it looks like. This is what the entire QGIS window looks like in Map Only view:

[image]

As you can see, this option turns off **all** of the menus, panels and other visible controls. The only way to disable it is to use the hotkey combo. Of course, if you didn't memorize the hotkey combo, you can't find it again, because you don't have access to the View menu anymore.

**How to un-toggle "Map Only" view mode?**

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I wasn't able to find the answer by googling "qgis map only view," but I did figure this out myself. I thought I'd post an answer here, and hopefully save others from the same problem.

**The hotkey combo to disable Map Only view mode is**

> Ctrl-Shift-Tab

Or, you can close the QGIS window (saving changes or not, as you prefer). When you re-open QGIS, it will still be in Map Only view, but you will have access to the menus again. Before opening another project, open the View menu and turn off Map Only mode.